# Unable to checkin in VSS

Tags: visual-sourcesafe

I am trying to check in file in Visual Source Safe, File is checked out and shows proper code difference. But when i am trying to check in, it completes without error but changes not getting merge.
This issue is observed for few files in VSS.

VSS version 8.0.500727.42

Answer (score 1):

Check your mapped with server folders with all hierarchy structure is matches with you original local folders).

Comment: Hi Ravindra, server folder hierarchy structure matches with local folders. I am able to check in other files from the this folder. Issue is only with two files in this folder.

Comment: Please try using show difference with show all files. Also if your server encoding is difference than your local files it will show difference (blue color file(s)), but actually it does not have any difference.

Comment: i have tried with folder diff(all files) option. it shows **code** difference properly. but still not able to checkin the file. Is there any 'lock' or 'unlock' mechanism? (May be file marked as lock by other user). _Note:_  No other user has check out this file.

Comment: Seems like bug in VSS considering your are correct. Check for support of VSS.